# What is isolation level, when 2 concurrent transaction trying to change it

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, transactions, isolation-level

I have two transaction working on same table.

```
BEGIN TRAN
SET TRAN ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
--something more
```

and second one

```
BEGIN TRAN
SET TRAN ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ
--something more
```

will be they working together on one of this level, or will be working on their own level ? What happend if one of this isolation level will be snapshot ?

Comment: Are these transactions "nested", both initiated on a single connection, or are they being initiated on separate connections?

Comment: They are invoked by different connection to databases. But are working concurrent

Comment: The current transaction isolation level is part of the session. If these commands execute concurrently, they are by definition on different sessions, so no, they aren't working together on levels. The transaction isolation level dictates what kinds of locks are taken when, and the sessions do, of course, respect each other's locks (or snapshots). Figuring out what happens when commands execute under different isolation levels can get complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) affects *the connection it's called on*.

It specifies what *this* connection will tolerate, what locking strategies this connection will use, etc. If another connection uses a different isolation level, both levels are "in effect" at the same time, for their respective connections. To understand how they'd interact, you need to consider them from each connection's perspective individually.